# Simple DC Circuit with 3 Devices

Tags: voltage

I am trying to connect a 1.5 V light bulb, buzzer and motor in series in a simple DC circuit with 3 volts. The problem I am having is that when I connect all 3 in series to 3 volts (2 D batteries) the only device that works is the buzzer. If I increase the voltage to 9 volts, the buzzer is louder but it is still the only device that works. Can someone explain why the bulb and motor still will not work with 9 volts? They all three will work if they are connected individually to 1.5 volts. I assume the buzzer has variable resistance so "steals" all the voltage?

Comment: why are you connecting the loads in series?

Comment: the buzzer lets only small current to pass ... it is not enough to run the motor or to light the lamp

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a schematic as well as datasheets for the components (e.g. buzzer).

Comment: Seems like connecting them in series is the problem.  Also, they would be all ON or all OFF.  Connecting them in parallel woul allow each load to operate independently.  Assuming all require 1.5V to work.

Comment: Why don't you post the photo of the piezo beeper here like you did on the other website forum so we can see that it uses much less current than the motor/fan or light bulb? Then it is obvious that it works in series with the others but the others do not work.

Answer (score 1):

In a [series circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits) the same current flows through all devices. If the devices need different amounts of current to operate then those that need more current may not work properly if those that draw less current restrict it.

If the devices were all *resistive* (ie. current draw is proportional to voltage according to [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)) then each device would get a proportion of the total voltage equal to its proportion of the total resistance. But buzzers, light bubs and motors are not purely resistive, so you can't just measure the resistance and calculate the operating current from it.

The buzzer may consist of an electromagnet and a contact that opens when the armature is attracted to the magnet, or it may have an electronic circuit that generates an oscillating waveform in a piezoelectric disc or speaker. It may draw pulses of current at the buzzing frequency, causing the average current to go up or down as it gets going.

An incandescent light bulb has a filament that heats up when current passes though it, increasing resistance and reducing current draw by about 10 times as it reaches maximum brightness. If the bulb doesn't get enough enough current to heat up then it will have low resistance and drop little voltage.

A brushed DC electric motor has an armature with coils that generate a voltage as it spins up, reducing current draw by 5~10 times as it reaches full speed. If it doesn't get enough initial current to spin up then it will also drop little voltage.

Due to these non-linear characteristics, whichever device is first to get sufficient current to start up may then 'starve' the other devices of current and 'hog' most of voltage. In your case it seems that the buzzer is the lowest current device, so it gets most of the voltage in the series circuit.

The simple answer to this problem is to wire the devices in [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits), with each one having a separate connection to the battery allowing it to draw whatever current it needs.

However you then have another problem, in that the light bulb is only rated for 1.5 V. At 3 V it will get too hot and quickly burn out, so you *need* something in series with it to drop the excess voltage. For this you can use a resistor that drops ~1.5 V at the bulb's rated current draw, eg. if the bulb is rated for 0.5 A at 1.5 V then you would use a 3 Ω resistor because (3 V - 1.5 V) / 0.5 A = 3 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

It is presumed that the rated voltage of the incandescent light bulb, buzzer and motor is 1.5 V DC.

The right way would be to connect the three of them in parallel to a 1.5 V DC source that is capable of supplying the total starting inrush current.

The reasons for the inrush would be cold resistance of the bulb and absence of back emf at motor start.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking the time to share your thoughts.